# Mod rewrite apache 2.4.9 from apache 2.2

Tags: apache

Ok, so I had a rule in the .htaccess of the site I am building that worked. Here it is:

```
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+)$ /news.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,QSA]
```

It transformed mysite.com/test/ to mysite.com/test.php (well, not to the end user but this is what it was doing in the background).

Now I had to update the server and apache 2.4.9 now gives me this error:

```
The requested URL /news.php/ was not found on this server.
```

Starting to bang my head on the wall here.

What I already did:

- Tried ^news/([0-9]+)$ /news.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,QSA]
- Tried ^/news([0-9]+)$ /news.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,QSA]
- Tried ^/news/([0-9]+)$ /news.php [L,NC,QSA]

I know I must have done something wrong in there but it was working fine before x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some how this is now working:

```
RewriteRule ^news(.*) /news.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,QSA]
```

I will have to re-code some logic in the php to check the querystring I think, but at least now it does find the files !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of .htaccess to something like "htaccess"  without the dot or "htaccess.txt" and use the AccessFileNAme [httpd.apache.org] directive to tell apache to use that new filename instead.